# @Configuration bean to set spring.application.name

Tags: spring-boot

What would be the appropriate way to set spring.application.name in an @Configuration file instead of within an applicaiton.properties file?

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: Give us the reason why you want to do that, maybe there could be a better solution.

Comment: Basically I want to set the application name using some information from the pom:
<artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
<version>myversion-SNAPSHOT</version>
myartifiact-myversion in some instances and myartifact in others.  So i was going to configure it to be set with some logic and profiles in an @Configuration class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically I want to set the application name the same as the
>   following: myartifiact-myversion myartifact
>   myversion-SNAPSHOT

From [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-automatic-expansion-maven) , you can use `@..@` placeholders to refer to properties in `pom.xml` if you use `spring-boot-starter-parent` (Normally most spring-boot project already use it) .

So in the `application.properties`:

```
spring.application.name=@artifactId@-@version@
```

Comment: That is what I had, I was just wanting to put some logic around it.  I found a workaround though.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear ... For putting some logic around , I would implement a `ApplicationContextInitializer` and add it to `SpringApplication` before running it.

Comment: so Im stuck again, what Im trying to do is spring.application.name=@artifactId@-@version@, but currently the @version@ = 1.6.0-SNAPSHOT and I want it to have logic to trim the "-SNAPSHOT"